# Removing duplicate values from a list if it meets conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write a for each loop to go through each row in in one sheet (sheet 2) to remove duplicates in another sheet (sheet 1).  I have had no luck researching either.

In sheet 1, I have a list of customer numbers in column B with the type of product they purchased in column c and the cost of that product in column d.  In another sheet 2, I have a list of customers in column a and list of products in column b.

I have been trying to write a for each loop to go through each row in sheet 2 to check the customer number and product, find all the duplicates in sheet 1 with the same customer number and product, and deleting the row with the higher balance.

Sheet 1

```
   A(Year)     B(Customer #)     C(Product Type)     D(Cost)
1) 2015        100               A                   1
2) 2015        100               A                   2
```

Sheet 2

```
   A(Customer #)     B(Product Type)   
1) 100               A
```

For example, if sheet 2 had 100 in column a and A in column b, it would delete row 2.

Comment: check here: https://www.ablebits.com/excel-remove-duplicates/compare-tables-duplicates.php

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you include the for each loop that you've already tried?

Comment: Can the data be sorted so that the lower costs are always toward the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the remove duplicates option within excel, would that solve your problem?  Or is Sheet 2 update to remove certain customer orders that you would also like to remove.

Edit:  To expand on this.  Take the list, sort it by customer and cost (low to high).  Then if you click remove duplicates, you'll have the option to select what columns to use as a basis for removing duplicates, so obviously remove cost, and then it'll clear out all but the topmost row, which as now been sorted to be the lowest value.

Comment: This actually worked as opposed to writing a macro.  Appreciate it!